# Get user email server-side facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So I want to get users email address with my server-side code.(I can get it on client side) My apps scope is set to:

```
"scopes":["public_profile","email"]}
```

What I'm able to-do at the moment is verify that the users token is valid. But I'd like to request the email as well - just to make sure on server side, that i can log the person in to my website. 
I use this address to verify the token belongs to my app:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=%REPLACE%&access_token=%REPLACE%
```

How should my request look like if I'd like to next ask for users email on server side?

Answer (score 3):

Appears another option (once/if you know the token belongs to your app) is:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`

by default it only returns id, if you want more, ex email:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`

which returns both id and email.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/<user_id>?access_token=<your_app_access_token>
```

will return:

```
{
   "id": "<id>",
   "email": "mihkel\u0040gmail.ee",
   "first_name": "Mihkel",
   "gender": "male",
   "last_name": "Lastname",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/<id>/",
   "locale": "en_US",
   "name": "Mihkel Lastname"
}
```

if you need only email you can set `fields=email` parameter :)

Answer (score 0):

You need USER ACCESS TOKEN to get user mail Id,

you can the access token from the response of API call
response.authResponse.accessToken;